# qt sorting of container of Type* elements

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom type Class1 in which `bool operator < (Class1& other);` was defined.
Also i have some container for example `QVector<Class1*> container;`
When I'm using `qSort(container.begin(),container.end());` items was sorted by their memory address.
Then i desided to implement `bool operator < (Class1* other);` but sorting is perfomed in the same way.

Comment: I think, less-then operator would be required only for using the classes as QMap-keys. It is not required for declaring containers using QVector or QList, so can't be (easily) used by container-template for sorting. The implementation should have first checked, if the less-then op is implemented in the class then call it, otherwise call pointer-address comparison. Not so easy. (However, this would probably work using weird Alexandresku's templace-tricks :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide a `LessThan` function to the [`qSort` function](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-2). Here's an example from the documentation:

> **void qSort ( RandomAccessIterator begin, RandomAccessIterator end, LessThan lessThan )**
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Uses the lessThan function instead of operator<() to compare the items.
>
> For example, here's how to sort the strings in a QStringList in case-insensitive alphabetical order:

```
 bool caseInsensitiveLessThan(const QString &s1, const QString &s2)
 {
     return s1.toLower() < s2.toLower();
 }

 int doSomething()
 {
     QStringList list;
     list << "AlPha" << "beTA" << "gamma" << "DELTA";
     qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), caseInsensitiveLessThan);
     // list: [ "AlPha", "beTA", "DELTA", "gamma" ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [variant](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-2) where you can provide your own comparator in the call:

```
qSort(container.begin(),container.end(),
    [](const Class1* first, const Class1* second)
    { return first->operator<(*second); });
```